# Yii Framework 2.0 sending ajax get request from sub domain to main domain

Tags: php, ajax, subdomain, yii2, cross-site

I try to send an AJAX GET request from a sub domain to a main domain. Below is my AJAX code.

```
$.get('http://my-yii2-website.com/controller/test-method', 
      {data: '1')}, 
      function(returnedData){

        alert(returnedData);

      }, 
      'json'
);
```

This above code resides in the sub domain. In the main domain I have the controller and action method that looks like following.

```
public function behaviors()
{
    $subDomain = 'http://subdomain.my-yii2-website.com';

    return [
        'corsFilter' => [
            'class' => \yii\filters\Cors::className(),
            'cors'  => [
                'Origin' => [$subDomain, ],
                'Access-Control-Request-Method' => ['GET', ],
                'Access-Control-Request-Headers' => ['*'],
                'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => null,
                'Access-Control-Max-Age' => 3600,
            ],
        ],
    ];
}

public function actionTestMethod()
{
    $request = Yii::$app->request;
    if($request->isAjax)
    {
          return json_encode('OK!');
    }
    else
    {
          return json_encode('ERROR');
    }
}
```

It does work. But due to the if-statement in the actionTestMethod(), it does not see the request as an AJAX request. It returns the predefined 'ERROR' message. I am working with Yii framework 2.0.

Comment: In your example your domains are different
http://my-yii2-website/controller/actionMethod

and http://subdomain.my-yii2-website.nl.

Maybe you miss .nl in ajax url

Comment: Just edited my question. In my original code I have checked, the domain url and the sub domain url are correct. I just don't understand why it is a bad request while I did define the POST method properly.

Comment: Next: actions array in cors branch is in wrong level. cors and actions branches should be siblings

Comment: You're trying to make a *post* request using `$.get`?! Give that and the error message you quote, it looks like you've shared the wrong piece of Ajax code.

Comment: @Panoptik: I have edited my code with the GET method. This time the AJAX GET method can reach the actionTestMethod in the main domain. But due to the if-statement it returns the predefined 'ERROR' message because it does not see the request as an AJAX request.

Comment: @Quentin: At the beginning I have tried to use the POST method with $.ajax(type: 'POST'); but it didn't work. So I then try with the GET method and have changed my code sample here into GET, but forget to change the question title. Why did I edit my question with the GET method? because It works with the GET method. But the next issue is that it does not see my request as an AJAX request.

Answer (score 0):

`isAjax` tests for the presence of an `X-Requested-With` header on the assumption that anyone making an Ajax request will set that (non-standard) header.

jQuery will set it by default for same origin requests. It will not set it for cross origin requests (because it is non-standard, normal CORS settings will reject it).

Either set it explicitly or use some other method to determine if the request is ajax or not.

(Note that, in general, "is ajax" is a bad test, "would like JSON instead of HTML" is normally a better test and you can key that off [the Accept header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html))

Comment: So how can I check if it is a AJAX request or not using any Yii 2.0 method? because otherwise I want the application to stop executing if it is not a AJAX request.

Comment: @OConnor — As I said, set the `X-Requested-With` header explicitly.